# Why sometimes dependency not contain version property in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I am a newbie of Maven, currently reading Hadoop source code, and found something interesting in some `pom.xml` files:

Some of the dependency node do not contain version node at all.

**Question**: why is it like this?

for instance, [this `pom.xml`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/pom.xml).

Comment: because the mentioned pom has a parent pom at its top, which specifies the missing versions

Comment: If you view this pom in your IDE, you will see a link on the left showing you where the version is actually defined. You can also obtain the "effective POM" showing you all the versions in one place.

Comment: @user1928863 you didn't accept any answer on this question. none of them was enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because specific version of dependency in **parent `pom.xml` file**

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/pom.xml

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: The parent pom defining several dependencies management is not the one you mentioned, I believe [its first child](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-project/pom.xml) (and parent of many modules, like the mentioned one by the OP) it's a better sample.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented at first, a pom file can have a parent (via [inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)) and such a parent may provide some governance and harmonization across all of its children. A classic case is to provide versioning for certain dependencies via a [`dependencyManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) section.

> is used by POMs to help manage dependency information across all of its children. If the `my-parent` project uses `dependencyManagement` to define a dependency on `junit:junit:4.0`, then POMs inheriting from this one can set their dependency giving the groupId=junit and artifactId=junit only, then Maven will fill in the version set by the parent. The benefits of this method are obvious. Dependency details can be set in one central location, which will propagate to all inheriting POMs.

The mentioned pom has indeed a parent pom:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-project-dist</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <relativePath>../../hadoop-project-dist</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Which in chain has [another parent pom](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-project/pom.xml) file which defines several dependencies as part of its dependencies management section.

---

If you really want to check the effective (merged) pom your build is using, you could run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective-pom.xml
```

And the [`maven-help-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) will produce an additional pom as specified by the command above, merging the current pom file and all of its anchestors.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you can inherit from parents folder in order to merge or inherit some properties. This can be the version of the modules. Usually you have a "super" POM in the root folder of your project and you put there all the commons dependencies in order to controll them in an easier way. I.e. If you must change one module version, you only need to change in the "super" POM and not in each POM inside each subfolder that need it. If you need more information about POM inheritance the documentation has a couple of useful examples.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance